# XmlTextReader.GetAttribute retorna o valor nulo

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

Fiz um código base em XML e eu gostaria de importar os atributos e valores de acordo com o código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- MAIN SCRIPT FILE FOR JAVA 7u80 MINECRAFT SERVER -->
<params count="3">
    <param name="commandLine" value="java.exe -jar @commandForge@ nogui" SerializeAs="[mscorlib]::System.Process" />
    <param name="commandForge" value="forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1448-1.7.10-universal.jar" SerializeAs="[mscorlib]::System.String" />
    <param name="previewOutput" value="True" SerializeAs="Boolean" />
</params>
```

E executei o seguinte código para pegar o atributo `count` do primeiro elemento:

```cs
internal void LoadXML()
        {
            try
            {
                if (s != null)
                {
                    KeysAndValues = new Dictionary<object, object>();
                    XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(s);

                    xmlreader.ReadStartElement("params");
                    int count = int.Parse(xmlreader.GetAttribute("count")); 
         // acontece o erro aqui na linha acima!

                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    {
                        var name= "";
                        var value = "";

                        xmlreader.ReadStartElement("param");
                        name = xmlreader.GetAttribute(0);
                        value = xmlreader.GetAttribute(1);
                        xmlreader.ReadEndElement();

                        KeysAndValues.Add(name, value);

                    }


                    xmlreader.ReadEndElement();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ExceptionForm exceptionA = new ExceptionForm(e);
                exceptionA.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
```

Logo depois disso eu compilo e executo a aplicação e aparece o seguinte:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Valor não pode ser nulo.
Nome do parâmetro: String
   em System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   em System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   em Start.XMLScriptParser.LoadXML() na C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Start\Start\XMLScriptParser.cs:linha 37
```

Sendo que eu já forneci todos os dados que ele pediu!

Código completo:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

namespace Start
{
    public class XMLScriptParser
    {
        Dictionary<object, object> KeysAndValues;
        Stream s;

        public XMLScriptParser(Stream s)
        {
            this.s = s;
        }

        public object GetValueFrom(object Key)
        {
            return KeysAndValues[Key];
        }

        public void TryParse() { LoadXML(); }

        internal void LoadXML()
        {
            try
            {
                if (s != null)
                {
                    KeysAndValues = new Dictionary<object, object>();
                    XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(s);

                    xmlreader.ReadStartElement("params");
                    int count = int.Parse(xmlreader.GetAttribute("count"));

                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    {
                        var name= "";
                        var value = "";

                        xmlreader.ReadStartElement("param");
                        name = xmlreader.GetAttribute(0);
                        value = xmlreader.GetAttribute(1);
                        xmlreader.ReadEndElement();

                        KeysAndValues.Add(name, value);

                    }


                    xmlreader.ReadEndElement();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ExceptionForm exceptionA = new ExceptionForm(e);
                exceptionA.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

O Mesmo quero fazer com este documento XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<params count="12">
    <param name="Locale" value="PT-BR" SerializeAs="[mscorlib]::String" />
    <param name="DisplayName" value="Nathan Ferreira" SerializeAs="[mscorlib]::String" />
    <param name="MainText" value="Start :: [Empty.xml]" SerializeAs="[mscorlib]::String" />
    <param name="ExceptionText" value="Ops! Tem algo errado" SerializeAs="[mscorlib]::String" />

    <param name="MainForm.Label1" value="Arquivo de script:" SerializeAs="[mscorlib]::String" />
    <param name="MainForm.Label2" value="Enviar Comando" SerializeAs="[mscorlib]::String" />
    <param name="MainForm.Label3" value="Uso de Mem. RAM" SerializeAs="[mscorlib]::String" />

    <param name="MainForm.Button1" value="Carregar e Iniciar" SerializeAs="[mscorlib]::String" />
    <param name="MainForm.Button2" value=">>" SerializeAs="[mscorlib]::String" />

    <param name="MainForm.Page1" value="Linha de comando" SerializeAs="[mscorlib]::String" />
    <param name="MainForm.Page2" value="Configuração do Script" SerializeAs="[mscorlib]::String" />

    <param name="MainForm.ProgressBarValue" value="0" SerializeAs="[mscorlib]::Int32" />

</params>
```

Comment: `xmlreader.GetAttribute("count")` está retornando `null`. Eu costumo abrir XML usando Linq, então não sei o que pode estar errado, mas vou testar aqui e tentar ver qual é o problema.

Comment: Como seria usando Linq? Eu quero fazer como se fosse uma lista com `param name` e `param value` tudo em um `SortedDictionary ` ou um `Dictionary` normal.

Comment: Vou pegar um exemplo.

Comment: ok aguardo!              .  .

Comment: Você conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Ainda não tive tempo de editar o código mas fique tranquilo amanha irei fazer isto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que o retorno de `xmlreader.GetAttribute("count")` está sendo `null` e, como o próprio erro diz, o valor passado para `int.Parse()` **não pode ser nulo.**

O erro eu realmente não sei onde está, talvez você precise pegar o atributo de uma maneira diferente, não sei.

Eu fiz um código de exemplo (usando Linq) com base no objetivo geral da rotina (que você explicou nos comentários)

> Eu quero fazer como se fosse uma lista com **param name** e **param value** tudo em um `SortedDictionary` ou um `Dictionary` normal.

O código abaixo retorna um `Dictionary` com a `Key` sendo o valor do atributo **name** e o `value` sendo o valor do atributo **value**.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("arq.xml");    
var count = doc.Descendants("params").FirstOrDefault()?.Attribute("count").Value;

var query = doc.Descendants("param")
                    .Select(x => new
                    {
                        Name = x.Attribute("name").Value,
                        Value = x.Attribute("value").Value
                    }).ToDictionary(o => o.Name, o => o.Value);
```

Perceba que eu não validei se os nós ou atributos realmente existem.